# How do we calculate the duration of a streaming session, and subsequently the cost for an individual App User, consuming the Google Speech APIs?

Tags: android, audio-streaming, price, google-cloud-speech, metering

I have a critical question regarding pricing model of Google Cloud Speech APIs. We are integrating Google Cloud Speech APIs in our Android App. Our use case is to continuously transcribe audio bytes getting from microphone. It can be few min to hours in duration.

Google Cloud Speech APIs charge $0.009 / 15 seconds, but as an Android app developer, we don’t know how much users will use our app and also not know how much a user will use or consume it. We also don't know how we can calculate each request and cost per request at client side for each app user.

**Question: How do we calculate the duration of a streaming session, and subsequently the cost of usage for an individual App User, consuming the Google Cloud Speech APIs?**

Comment: i don't think your question is right for this site, as it's asking a lot about the specific policies of the google cloud speech api, however i'm not entirely sure so i won't vote to close, but others might.

Comment: I added the question to do more on-topic. Questions about the business model of how set the policy are off-topic here.